# Update google chrome on ubuntu 22.04.1

Tags: updates, google-chrome, google

Update google chrome on ubuntu 22.04.1 - How to correctly update google chrome on ubuntu 22.04.1?

Comment: What do you mean? Have you tried it incorrectly? What did you try? How did it fail? What version do you have now and what version do you want to have? Please ***edit*** (don't answer in comments) your question and clarify.

Comment: You should also update Ubuntu itself to version 22.04.4. With the one you have, it lacks some two years of updates.

Comment: Your details (*if correct*) imply you've not applied any security fixes since before February 2023; is this correct?  as that could be your issue. This post (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/02/24/ubuntu-22-04-2-lts-released/) shows the ISO relate date of 22.04.2, however INSTALLED systems upgraded BEFORE that date by near two weeks.  and as @mikewhatever has already stated a fully upgraded 22.04 system reports itself as 22.04.4.

Comment: @terdon sorry, I can't to edit the title.

Comment: @mikewhatever thanks for your contribution

Comment: @guiverc I read the post you mentioned and I ran the **sudo apt upgrade**. My ubuntu  **was 22.04.1** LTS **now is 22.04.4**.

Answer (score 0):

After investigation on internet, I found the solution:

1. **crtl+alt+T** to open ubuntu terminal
2. **sudo apt update** recommended by ubuntu https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/02/24/ubuntu-22-04-2-lts-released/ (thanks @guiverc)
3. **sudo apt upgrade** to install new packages
4. **google-chrome-stable-version** to check the currently installed google chrome version
5. **sudo apt --only-upgrade install google-chrome-stable** to update google chrome - https://linuxgenie.net/update-google-chrome-ubuntu-22-04/

Comment: `sudo apt update` will not "*update ubuntu*" as you state; it will only update software lists as to what upgrade/fixes are available. You need to apply those via `apt upgrade` which you don't mention. What you actually suggest here will leave your machine vulnerable to numerous security flaws due to your advocating an non-updated machine which would be safer offline (*you're only upgrading a single package & leaving your machine open to many online attacks as a result*)

Answer (score 0):

Chrome can be installed with simply typing `sudo apt install google-chrome-stable` in the terminal, and this works for the upgrade as well. If this method fails, try to reinstall it with `sudo apt reinstall google-chrome-stable`. If that solution produces an error,  try to get DEBs from the official site, open them with „Software Install”, click the remove button and then install it again. The /opt/google/chrome folder is not deleted, so your data is kept.